# cfquery grouping, counts & maxrows

Tags: coldfusion

I'll start by explaining what I'm doing - I feel a 'real world' explanation will make this easier to understand.  I have a Category & Subcategory list for an online store.  The database table is configured in a simple fashion - id, category_name and subcategoryof - subcategoryof being a 0 to represent a top-level category.

In the main index of the store, I'm listing all categories and subcategories - using a combination of a single query using a left join, and cfoutput within the cfoutput query (code pasted below).  This works well and allows me to style the top-level categories and subcategories well enough to distinguish between them.

However, the list is getting a bit long now and a fair amount of scrolling is now required to navigate the page.  What I would like to do is this;

Output all the top-level categories as at present
Output only 2 of the Subcategories
Show a count of how many extra subcategories there are (i.e +7 More Subcategories).

Now, I will actually output everything as I do now - however after the 2nd subcategory, I'll set the following subcategories as hidden and use the '+7 More Subcategories' text to toggle the display (still with me here?).

My problem, and question, is this - how do I get a count of subcategories for use with my '+x More Subcategories' text?  I assume my current plan of using an incremental count to determine the point at which I start hiding rows is the best route?

Existing code below

```
<cfquery name="getcategories">
SELECT p.ID AS CategoryID, p.Cat_Name as CategoryName, p.Cat_Shortname, c.ID AS SubCategoryID, c.Cat_Name as SubCategoryName, c.Cat_Shortname AS SubCatShortname
FROM    product_categories p LEFT JOIN product_categories c ON p.ID = c.SubcategoryOf
WHERE  p.SubcategoryOf = 0
</cfquery> 
<ul>
   <cfoutput query="getcategories" group="CategoryName">
    <li class="catli"><a href="">#CategoryName#</a></li> 
    <cfoutput><li class="subli"><a href="">#SubcategoryName#</a></li></cfoutput>
        <li class="subli moreli"><a href="">+ 7 More Subcategories</a></li>
   </cfoutput>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<ul>
   <cfset SubcategoryNames = []>
   <cfoutput query="getcategories" group="CategoryName">
    <li class="catli"><a href="">#CategoryName#</a></li> 
        <cfoutput>
          <cfset arrayAppend(subcategoryNames, SubcategoryName)>
        </cfoutput>
        <cfloop from="1" to="#max(arrayLen(subcategoryNames),2)#" index="i">
            <li class="subli"><a href="">#SubcategoryName[i]#</a></li>
        </cfloop>
        <cfif arrayLen(subcategoryNames) GT 2>
          <li class="subli moreli">
            <a href="">+ #arrayLen(subcategoryNames) - 2# More Subcategories</a>
          </li>
        </cfif>
   </cfoutput>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks Henry, thats a huge help.  For the benefit of anyone else trying to do the same, your code worked fine but I had to make one small alteration to get the output to display correctly; <li class="subli"><a href="">#SubcategoryName[i]#</a></li>