# Coldfusion - Clearing & Appending Arrays

Tags: arrays, coldfusion

I asked a question here yesterday ([cfquery grouping, counts & maxrows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7680345/cfquery-grouping-counts-maxrows)) to which this is related.  That question would successfully answered in as much as the count aspect is working successfully.  However, I'm getting strange results with another aspect that I can quite figure out.

The scenario is this - I'm returning top-level categories and subcategories in a single query, the subcategories being returned by nesting cfoutput.  The result works, with one exception - the subcategories are always returning the full list - i.e if I limit the initial output to return only 2 rows on screen, I'm always getting the first 2 rows from the first top-level category - now the first 2 rows from the 'current' top level category.

I've tried clearing the array within the cfoutput query, within the cfloop etc - all without success.

I've pasted my code below, and attached a screenshot of the current out it generates.  Any pointers on this before I lose all my hair would be gratefully accepted!

```
<cfquery name="getcategories">
SELECT p.ID AS CategoryID, p.Cat_Name as CategoryName, p.Cat_Shortname, c.ID AS SubCategoryID, c.Cat_Name as SubCategoryName, c.Cat_Shortname AS SubCatShortname
FROM    product_categories p LEFT JOIN product_categories c ON p.ID = c.SubcategoryOf
WHERE  p.SubcategoryOf = 0
</cfquery> 
<cfset subcategoryNames = ArrayNew(1)>
        <cfoutput query="getcategories" group="CategoryName">
        <li class="catli">CategoryName : #CategoryName#</li> 
        <cfoutput>

          <cfset arrayAppend(subcategoryNames, SubcategoryName)>
          <p>ArrayAppend : #SubcategoryName#<br /></p>
        </cfoutput>

        <cfloop from="1" to="2" index="i">
            <li class="subli">SubcategoryName : #SubcategoryName[i]#</li>
        </cfloop>

        <cfif arrayLen(subcategoryNames) GT 2>
        <p>ArrayLen is GT 2</p>
          <li class="subli moreli">
            + #arrayLen(subcategoryNames) - 2# More Subcategories
          </li>
            <!--- Extra Subcategories --->
            <p>Extra Subcategories</p>
                <cfloop from="3" to="#arrayLen(subcategoryNames)#" index="r">
                <li class="subli">SubcategoryName : #SubcategoryName[r]#</li>
                </cfloop>

            <!--- End Extra Subcategories --->

        </cfif>

        </cfoutput>
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Don't forget to mark an accepted answer if this one was solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should just be able to switch these two lines:

```
<cfset subcategoryNames = ArrayNew(1)>
<cfoutput query="getcategories" group="CategoryName">
```

To this:

```
<cfoutput query="getcategories" group="CategoryName">
    <cfset subcategoryNames = ArrayNew(1)>
```

That will reset your array at the beginning of each new top-level category.

You could also leave them in their original order, and just do this:

```
<cfset subcategoryNames = ArrayNew(1)>
<cfoutput query="getcategories" group="CategoryName">
    <cfset ArrayClear(subcategoryNames) />
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Dan.  That was my first thought too, but for some reason - it doesn't.  The output is exactly the same.

Comment: Ah Ha! I have just had a brainwave! One of the fields in the getCategories query is subcategoryName, and because I'm not using the nested output to actually output these subcategories anymore, it's outputting from the primary query and ignoring the Array completely.  It's using the array to figure out how many rows to output, but not the actual content of it.  So, I guess I need to figure out how to loop through the array instead.

Comment: @Lee (Edit) - Maybe I need more coffee, but could you not just skip the array and run the inner `<cfoutput>` twice instead? The first time count the total subcategories, the second display the subcategories. (Assuming you cannot generate the totals in sql that is). Also, be sure to ORDER BY CategoryName first, or the output may not work properly.

Comment: Thinking about this, I find it strange resetting the array did not work. It should do the trick. Unless maybe the results are not ordered correctly. They +must+ be ordered by the grouped field ie `p.Cat_Name` first.

Comment: I think he was having some scope issues, due to a column name being the same as the array name.

Comment: You are right. I missed the omitted "s" in `SubcategoryName[r]`. Knew I should have had more coffee ;)